# test method always fails. why isn't the soql returning any records?

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I've been running a chatter tutorial and ran across something I don't understand.

First off here's the [link to the tutorial](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_chatter/chatter.pdf) .

The following code is straight out of the tutorial and works, except for the test method. The test method fails on the first assert() every time. The reason it fails is because the array is always empty.

Why is the test method failing but the visualforce page works fine? Better yet, why isn't the getRecentTextUpdates() returning anything in the test method?

```
<apex:page controller="NewsFeedController" sidebar="false">
  <h1>News Feed</h1>
  <apex:form >
      <apex:inputText value="{!feedUpdate}"/>
      <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!go}" reRender="recent"/>

      <apex:outputPanel id="recent">
          <apex:dataList value="{!recentTextUpdates}" var="update">
              <apex:outputText value="{!update.body}"></apex:outputText>
          </apex:dataList>
      </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page> 

public class NewsFeedController {

    @isTest
    static void testUpdates() {
        NewsFeedController con = new NewsFeedController();
        con.feedUpdate = 'Hi';
        con.go();
        List<NewsFeed> newsFeed = con.getRecentTextUpdates();
        System.debug('My NewsFeed Size: ' + newsFeed.size());
        System.assert(newsFeed.size() > 0);
        System.assertEquals('Hi', newsFeed[0].Body);
    }

    public PageReference go() {
        FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
        feedItem.Type = 'TextPost';
        feedItem.ParentId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        feedItem.Body = this.feedUpdate;
        insert feedItem;

        return null;
    }

    public List<NewsFeed> getRecentTextUpdates() {
        List<NewsFeed> newsFeed = [SELECT Type, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, Body FROM NewsFeed WHERE Type = 'TextPost' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 10];

        return newsFeed;
    }


    public String feedUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Changing NewsFeed to FeedItem in the test method and getRecentTextUpdates() makes the test pass. Not sure why NewsFeed won't work - coz Users should be able to only query their own NewsFeed. Unless there are limitations on querying in a Test Method. I tried System.runAs to no avail

Comment: thanks, FeedItem works when replacing the NewsFeed. Pretty Odd.

Comment: @techtrekker still, I have no idea why NewsFeed works in normal runtime but not in the testing context.

Comment: It is odd. I wonder if it has something to do with "Users can only query their own news feed". System.runAs isnt cutting it either.

Comment: well even so, it's the same user inserting and querying it in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to check API version, I faced similar issue in API v24 update. I have to lower down API version 23 to get rid of it. More details in this blog post here : http://www.tgerm.com/2012/04/chatter-apex-test-case-bug-in-api.html

Comment: So definitely a bug then, wonder if salesforce know about this. Nothing on the Known Issues Index

Comment: True, I think its not listed yet here : https://sites.secure.force.com/success/apex/issues_index

Comment: @AbhinavGupta changing the Controller class to API 23 fixed the issue. Anything after 23 I had to replace NewsFeed with FeedItem in order to get the test method to work.

Comment: Did either of you guys list this as an issue? If Not, I will.

Comment: Please list that or post as an idea @fourq, as I don't see a way to post issue on the issue list page(it seems internal)

Comment: Please check my answer below, this isn't a bug, just a change in test behaviour.

Comment: @PJC This isn't a change in test behavior. I'm aware of SeeAllData and how it works, but the thing is that the test method is entering the data  within the test, and works fine if NewsFeed is replaced with FeedItem so it's not a data view scope issue.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I'll create a case and have them escalate it to the dev division so they can determine if it is in fact a bug.

Answer (score 6):

From API version 24, Salesforce stop supporting real records in test cases. To access the real records, add the tag (SeeAllData=true) in your test class,

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class TestCase{
  static testMethod void TestMethodOne() { 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! I was trying all various combinations. Saved my day.